# What's the reason of the syntax error while concatenating strings?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, string-concatenation

What's the exact syntax problem in the following string concatenation?

```
str(10) + ':' + {:02}.format(00)
```

Comment: The last one is not a string, you need the quotes: `'{:02}'.format(00)`.
But why not directly: `'{}:{:02}'.format(10, 0)`?

Comment: On a side note to what @FrancisColas points out is the syntax error... you could since you're already using `str.format` write that as `'{}:{:02}'.format(10, 0)` ?